# What is the probability of a car breaking down the kth time in the nth drive?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

If the probablity that a car breaks down is 10%.
What is the probability that the kth time the car breaks down is in the nth drive?

Would I use a binomial distribution for this? How would I account and make the kth break down on the nth drive?

We want k-1 breakdowns in n-1 drives first? Then a breakdown on the nth drive?

So...

$${n-1 \choose k-1}(0.1)^{k-1}(0.9)^{n-k}$$

would give you k-1 breakdowns in n-1 drives?

And the probability of a breakdown on the nth drive is just 0.1 right?

So would the following be the answer?
$${n-1 \choose k-1}(0.1)^{k-1}(0.9)^{n-k} \times 0.1$$

Comment: yes, your answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. Your solution to this problem is absolutely correct.